# ExtJS: How detach or promote source code HtmlEditor?

Tags: javascript, extjs, html-editor

How detach or promote source code mode window of HtmlEditor in another textarea?
I mean , How source code when typing in HtmlEditor may be displayed in another textarea element?

I create form with HtmlEditor & form with Textarea, and I assume that it is necessary to attach listner to 'textareafield' and get data from HtmlEditor textarea in source mode, but do not know how it to make.

```
{
    xtype: 'htmleditor',
    listeners: {
       }
    },

 ...

  {
    xtype: 'form',
    layout: {
      type: 'fit'
    },
    title: 'Source Code',
    flex: 1,
    items: [
    {
      xtype: 'textareafield',
      id:'textareaEl'
    }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? What do you mean by 'detach' or 'promote'?

Comment: I mean , display source code in another textarea when typing in HtmlEditor textarea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it)

```
  {
    xtype: 'htmleditor',
    id:'seditor',
    listeners: {
      render: function(){
    this.textareaEl.on('keydown', function() {
      this.fireEvent('sync', this, this.textareaEl.getValue());
    }, this, { buffer: 2 });
      },
      sync: function(sender, html){
      }
    },
    style: 'background-color: white;',
    hideLabel: true,
    labelPad: 0
    }
```

Comment: And how is that different from my answer? Thank you for un-accepting it :)

Comment: For me `textareaEl` was only available in `initialize` (extJS 4.2.2) , not yet in `render`.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything like this in standard component. I guess you can create text area yourself and update it periodically with the data from `htmleditor`.

Comment: In it a problem that the example is necessary to me how to transfer data provided that I use xtype for creation of objects.

Comment: I never done it, and I don't have an example - my advise was simply from experience working with ExtJs. I think it's doable - check events like 'update' and methods getValue(), setValue() for these tow classes.